# To show $f$ conatined in oval is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ is connected open and let $f\in O(\Omega)$ Suppose $f(\Omega) \subset L$ where $L:=\{x+iy \in \mathbb{C} \vert x^{2k} + y^{2k} = 1 \}$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, k >1$ 
Prove that $f$ is constant.

My attempt : I have proved that holomorphic $f$ contained in a circle is constant by showing a map between circle and real line.

I thought here if one can show that set $L$ can be mapped to a circle one-one then it is obvious. I am unable to show this mapping. 
Is this approach correct ?

EDIT : without using open mapping theorem.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the open mapping theorem?

Comment: I was asked to prove using basic principles and it would be useful if I learn it. Also it was in my exam and I wasn't able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this using the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  Writing $f=u+iv$, differentiating the identity $u^{2k}+v^{2k}=1$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ gives $$2k(u_xu^{2k-1}+v_xv^{2k-1})=0$$ and $$2k(u_yu^{2k-1}+v_yv^{2k-1})=0.$$
Combining this with Cauchy-Riemann, we find that $$v_x=-u_x(u/v)^{2k-1}=-v_y(u/v)^{2k-1}=u_y(u/v)^{4k-2}=-v_x(u/v)^{4k-2}$$ at any point such that $v\neq 0$.  Since $(u/v)^{4k-2}$ can only be nonnegative, $v_x$ must vanish whenever $v$ does not vanish.  It then follows easily that $v_y$, $u_x$, and $u_y$ must also vanish whenever $u$ and $v$ do not vanish.  But note that when $u$ vanishes, $v$ cannot vanish, and so the equations above imply $v_x=v_y=0$ and so $u_x=u_y=0$ as well by Cauchy-Riemann.  Similarly, when $v$ vanishes, $u$ cannot vanish, so again all the partial derivatives vanish.  So all the partial derivatives vanish everywhere, and $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the Open Mapping Theorem. Note that the image of $f$ is contained in a curve.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I want to do it without open mapping theorem.